# Loss of a bit when converting from Byte array to hex

Tags: java, encryption, key, generator

I managed to generate a 256 bit key with `CipherKeyGenerator` but when converting the result (in `byte []`) to hex I obtain 64 bytes, which is normal, but when converting those bytes into bits I only have 255 bits and have no idea about where this loss could come from.

I have tried several encoding methods to switch from byte array to hex but always with the same result. I supposed a link with the LSB or something like that.

```
KeyGenerationParameters param = new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 256);

CipherKeyGenerator KeyGen = new CipherKeyGenerator();
KeyGen.init(param);                             
byte[] KeyByte = KeyGen.generateKey();

String KeyHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(KeyByte);
System.out.println("Your key is : " + KeyHex);
```

Does someone have an idea about what is going on? 
Thanks for your advice!

Comment: first bit is zero?

Comment: Sadely it seems to be something esle. When I directly converte my Byte array to binary it gaves me a string starting with a "-" and I don't know why. It could be part of the problem. Maybe a problem with the byte [0] element, still searching.